# XML to Excel to XML again Denormalized value error

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to upload an XML I created in note to excel then populate it with data and export it into XML again. I'm doing this to easily populate the XML file.

The XML file I have below properly imports the data to Excel but the problem occurs when I want to export. I get an error saying the data is "denormalized". I noticed this error happens after I add the second element "< shipment >".

How can I solve this issue?

```
<CISDocument>

<ApiHeader>
    <OperationName>addPreBuiltLoad</OperationName> 
    <ClientID>test</ClientID> 
</ApiHeader>

<ApiHeader>
    <OperationName>addPreBuiltLoad</OperationName> 
    <ClientID>test</ClientID> 
</ApiHeader>


<shipment>
    <shipmentname>001</shipmentname>
</shipment>

</CISDocument>
```